# Grouping On the basis of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want the unique list of elements from XML document. If the occurrence of element is more than 1, i want to have the last occurrence in my output:

Please refer the below XML for getting unique list:

```
<Organization>
   <Fund id="F01" name="HighVista I Ltd Partnership"/>
   <Fund id="F01" name="HighVista II Limited Partnership"/>
   <Fund id="F02" name="HighVistaLand I, Ltd."/>
   <Fund id="F02" name="HighVistaLand II, Ltd."/>
   <Fund id="F03" name="HighVista III Limited Partnership"/>
</Organization>
```

The transform should output the below result:

```
<Organization>
   <Fund id="F01" name="HighVista II Limited Partnership"/>
   <Fund id="F02" name="HighVistaLand II, Ltd."/>
   <Fund id="F03" name="HighVista III Limited Partnership"/>
</Organization>
```

*Please note the change in name attribute of Fund with id F01 and F02.

Need the sample code in XSLT1.0 - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well your previous post and the answer in [How to get value of unique XML element by using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771031/how-to-get-value-of-unique-xml-element-by-using-xslt) apply, simply define the key based on the attribute `<xsl:key name="by-id" match="Fund" use="@id"/>` and then make use of `<xsl:copy-of select="Fund[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-id', @id)[last()])]"/>`. The other stuff you should be able to infer from the previous complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reference - In this case i have tried to use similar code but unable to get the desired result. As per the previous solution i felt comfortable to use because the tags were separate - here i am stucked because of multiple attributes. How do i use multiple attributes for getting unique set of result?

Comment: Thanks - It Worked - was missing a tag to use.